# Inkscape and Latex Line Spacing

Tags: pdftex, inkscape

I have exported a figure from inkscape to latex using the .pdf_text method. Everything is working fine but I would like to be able to change the line spacing of the text which was exported. Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You should import the graphic without any text and then overlay the text with TikZ or similar. Altering the text as you describe would be nigh impossible with TeX. **edit** can you elaborate on the 'pdf_text' method? I'm unfamiliar.

Comment: Open the `.pdf_tex` file. You will see, that every bit of text is placed using `\put(x,y){\color[rgb]{r,g,b}\makebox(0,0)[lb]{\smash{text}}}`. To move the text around, adjust the pair `(x,y)`. This is a bit tedious, but will serve its purpose and if you don't want to spend too much time on it, this is better than overlaying the picture using TikZ.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you. A suggestion: Do us a favour and change your username to something more telling than "user1234".